# What happens if I have two visas?

Tags: germany, uk-visa, blue-card, job-hunting

I got two job opportunities one from UK and another from Germany. For UK I needed exempt visa which I got easily but somehow I got confused and applied for blue card visa too for Germany.

Last night one of my senior told me that the opportunity in UK is much better than Germany so I am thinking if I get my blue card visa can I still go to UK?

Comment: You can simply not use the blue card visa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Germany and the UK are separate countries with separate immigration systems (despite the fact that they are both EU countries).  If Germany approves your blue card application then you simply will not use that visa.  The UK won't care about it.